# How to run meta pixel from external js

Tags: javascript

I want to run meta pixel from external js file with:

`<script async src="/includes/js/meta.js"></script>`

I have js file like this now:

```
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
{if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,document,'script',
'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
fbq('init', '123456789');
fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
  content_ids: ['123'], // 'REQUIRED': array of product IDs
  content_type: 'product', // RECOMMENDED: Either product or product_group based on the content_ids or contents being passed.
});
```

What to add in js that script will run?

I try many options and don't work...